# How to re-use text values in a webform?

Tags: 7, users, webforms

[image]I am using webform and with all the tons of modules available so far there was virtually nothing I had to compromise on.

One thing I am stuck with is re-using user text input. Is this possible without writing a custom webform module on a multi-page form:

1. user initially enters some text in 4 textfields
2. populate form checkboxes with those values?

There is the token module installed but I can't figure out a way to populate the checkboxes dynamically (coming from the user and not from a premade select list). The webform_ajax module tells me I can't use it on multi-page forms.

Any suggestions how to achieve something like this where the user enters something and this shows up later in the form?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to use hook_webform_select_options_info. How can I target the specific webform, text and select field? Devel does not show any webform ID. The screenshot shows textfield and selectlist information

From the link

```
function hook_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();
  $items['customusergroups'] = array(
 'title' => t('Your user groups'), 
 'options callback' => 'webform_options_days', 
 // 'file' => 'includes/webform.options.inc',
 );
 return $items;
}
```

Comment: You can give them the value with the form_state. Check the hook_form_alter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook in webform called [hook_webform_select_options_info](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_select_options_info/7), that allows you to build a dynamic list of $items[] (return $items), which will be used as the list of options for your component.  What you put into this list can obviously be anything - i.e. how you decide what to put in is up to you.

I used it recently to create a multi-route dynamic web form where the path through the webforms is determined by a decision tree.  Ever option on every question is loaded from a JSON file, and depending on the answer, the next question (which could be any one) is shown.